# How could I use hyperopt to optimize a vector that sums up to 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, hyperopt

I am using hyperopt to search for the hyperparameters of the algorithm. There are three numbers to be optimized: `w1`, `w2` and `w3`. The three numbers should satisfy the condition that `s1+w2+w3=1`.
I defined search space like this:

```
space = {
        'w1': hp.unifrom('w1', 0, 1),
        'w2': hp.unifrom('w2', 0, 1),
        'w3': hp.unifrom('w3', 0, 1),
}
```

The problem is that they cannot be summed up to 1, which is not what I hope it can. How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

To me, you have two possibilities

First, using softmax

```
space = {
        'w1': hp.uniform('w1', 0, 10), # 10 instead of 1 to cover almost all the space
        'w2': hp.uniform('w2', 0, 10),
        'w3': hp.uniform('w3', 0, 10),
}

# in your objective function, args is the name of your parameter argument

w1, w2, w3 = scipy.special.softmax([args["w1"], args["w2"], args["w3"]])
```

Second, using proportion of the rest

```py
space = {
        'w1': hp.uniform('w1', 0, 1),
        'w2': hp.uniform('w2', 0, 1),
}

# in your objective function, args is the name of your parameter argument

w1 = args["w1"]
w2 = (1 - args["w1"]) * args["w2"]
w3 = (1 - args["w1"]) * (1 - args["w2"])
```

I would say the second is the best if you have 3 values to compute, but the first is better if you have more

Comment: This answer actually works. As a side note: the return value from the fmin is the values before softmax, so don't forget to apply softmax to it!